# ramification of a rational prime in conjugate fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ramification

Let $p\in\mathbb{Z}$ be a rational prime. Let $f(x)\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial. If $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are two roots of $f$, we know that the fields $K_1=\mathbb{Q}(\theta_1)$ and $K_2=\mathbb{Q}(\theta_2)$ are isomorphic and their discriminants are same. So $p$ ramifies in $K_1$ iff $p$ ramifies in $K_2$. Is there any other way to arrive at this fact without using the fact that $p$ ramifies in a field iff $p$ divides the discriminant ?

Also, say we know that the factorization of $\langle p\rangle$ in $K_1$: $$pO_1=P_1^{e_1}\dots P_k^{e_k}$$

I have a guess that the factorization of $\langle  p\rangle$ in $K_2$ will be of the form
$$pO_2=\mathfrak{P}_1^{e_1}\dots \mathfrak{P}_k^{e_k}$$

Basically, the ramification indices of $P_i$ and $\mathfrak{P}_i$ are same. I also think that the corresponding inertia degrees will be same.

Is my guess correct ? If so, how to prove it ?

Comment: if $f \in K[x]$ is irreducible and $f(\theta_i) = 0$ then $K(\theta_i) \simeq K[x]/(f)$, so your two fields are isomorphic, and the splitting behavior of $p$ has to be the same in both

Comment: Yes, I agree. But what does it imply in the context of this question ?

Comment: ? the isomorphism means that $K_1$ and $K_2$ are the same field up to a renaming of some elements, so that $pO_1 = P_1^{e_1}\ldots P_k^{e_k} \implies p O_2 = \sigma(pO_1) = \sigma(P_1)^{e_1}\ldots \sigma(P_k)^{e_k}$  where $\sigma$ is the renaming function $K_1 \to K_2$